# Scala: How do you add a value to an existing int, via if-else?

Tags: scala

Why does this cause IntelliJ to say `Cannot resolve symbol +=`

```
var num: Int = 1
num += if (true) 1 else 2
```

and this causes `Cannot resolve symbol +`

```
var num: Int = 1
num = num + if (true) 1 else 2
```

but this works fine?

```
var num: Int = 1
num += 2
```

How do I add a non-hard-coded value to an existing int variable?

(Also doesn't work with `val num`)

Comment: What error did you get when it "didn't work"?

Comment: Right. Reload for a clearer question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to wrap `if-else` statement in braces:

```
num += (if (true) 1 else 2)
```

otherwise Scala compiler tries to interpret first token (`if`) as `Int`, but it's a `String`, thus compilation fails.

Comment: Excellent, thank you. And it must be `var num` not `val num`.

Comment: No you can actually make it a val.

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek If I make it a val, IntelliJ flags it with "Reassignment to val". With var it works.

Comment: Well your example would definitely be possible to write as a val expression, just right now you initialize it with 1 and then add stuff to it later. You could use a different val there for that intermediate result or even just add 1 more in your then and else case. Of course I don't know your actual use case...

Comment: @SebastiaanvandenBroek This in a scala worksheet works: `var num: Int = 1;
num += (if (true) 1 else 2)`. Change it tot `val`, and it flags it as I said.

Comment: Ok, you're right in saying this exact example cannot be a val since it's obviously being modified later :) but it can be rewritten easily using only val.

Comment: @MirMasej: what makes you think an implicit conversion is involved here?

Comment: @SethTisue I have updated the answer. The compiler error is: `expected Int but found String`. `If`is a keyword, so I don't think implicit conversion is involved here.

Comment: Is that IntelliJ saying that? The Scala REPL says `error: illegal start of simple expression`, pointing to the `if`.

Comment: No, Scala worksheet. To be more precise both errors are printed in it.